# Vlookup formula works with some months, gets #value error with others

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here's my formula:

`=IFERROR(((VLOOKUP($D$2,UOS!$A$18:$AC$31,5))/30)*$G$2,"")`

The `$D$2` field is populated with `=Text(c1,"mmmm")`

When I use this formula and `$D$2` is January, February, March, May, June, July, September, October or November - the formula works. But when `$D$2` is April, August, or December it doesn't work.

The table array is all formatted the same for the month.

The error that I get if I remove the IFERROR is `#value`

I have tried everything that I can think of - formatting, direct key of month into D2, etc.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num) assumes that the table
is sorted by the fundamental sort orders (alphabetical, numerical, and chronological). 
Since `D2` is a text value
(and I assume Column `A` contains the text strings `January`, `February`, …),
alphabetic sorting comes into play. 
“April”, “August”, and “December” come before “January” alphabetically;
that’s why they are failing.
You need to change your formula to

```
=IFERROR(((VLOOKUP($D$2, UOS!$A$18:$AC$31, 5, FALSE))/30)*$G$2,"")
```

to look for an exact match, and not expect the list to be sorted alphabetically.

---

“February” comes before “January” alphabetically, too; are you sure that it is working?

Comment: Thank you. Oddly the other months worked, but this does solve the issue. Thanks